# Representing a System / Application in FHIR

Tags: hl7-fhir

I am looking to develop a FHIR based/derived API to support cross system/organisation functions.  Primarily for the purposes of audit, and to a lesser degree access control, I would like the initiating system to include** information that describes the origin of the call.  This includes:

- Source user
- Source organisation
- Source application (i.e. application name and version)

The first two items can easily be represented with Practitioner however I can't find any resources that could be used to carry source application.

Does anybody know of any resources that could be used for this purpose?  Where possible I want to avoid using extensions.

** This is actually being included in an oAuth Client Credentials flow where the calling system obtains a token by providing a system level shared secret and origin.  This token is then supplied to the FHIR API method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question

The Device resource covers what I need:

http://hl7.org/fhir/device.html

Comment: Here's a thing, the Device resource has a codeable concept for type with a 1..1 cardinality.  It looks like the coding scheme for this is linked to the GMDN Database which is a commercial coding dictionary.  Odd choice for an open specification.

Comment: Although looking at the samples, SNOMED is used

Comment: The binding is "preferred", which means you can use others.  However, FHIR typically doesn't even make "preferred" bindings to commercial code systems, so you could certainly submit a change request raising this as an issue.  As well, the 1..1 can be satisfied with CodeableConcept.text in situations where a code isn't available.  (Would be good to have this explicitly noted in usage notes, so another change request might be appropriate there . . .)